# How to add floating div to BeEF projects scripts?

Tags: javascript

In the BeEF project there is a script that executes a fake Flash update with a grey background and an image. The problem is that when the user scrolls down, the background and the image are still at the top of the page. So I tried to edit the script and add some jQuery code to make it move with the visitor when he/she scrolls down, but I couldn't do it.

Comment: This looks more like a programming question.

Comment: Show what you've done, provide more information